# quick way to uninstall applications

Tags: 4.3-jelly-bean, samsung-nexus-10

I did a factory default reset and wipe to get rid of games that children put on my Nexus 10, however, I selected to allow Google to backup applications. Does that mean that all the games will come back automatically?

What is the meaning of the 11 identical Google Play store icons on the notification bar (top of screen).

Answer (score 0):

The games will not come back automatically.

11 Play Store icons mean that 11 apps were installed/updated.